# Custom style sheet tag in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, stylesheet, add-filter

I'd like to custom stylesheet code in wordpress.

```
global $is_chrome;
if($is_chrome){
    add_filter("style_loader_tag", function($tag){
        return str_replace("rel='stylesheet' " ,"rel='preload' as='style' onload=\"this.rel='stylesheet'\" ",  $tag);
    });
}
```

but this is effectable for css in asset folder.
this is not good for [themes > mytheme > ooo.css].

how can i get through this.

thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Enqueueing styles is the proper way to add a style sheet in WordPress

Paste the below code in `functions.php` and change **path** and **filename.css** to your **path** and **filename**

```
   function themename_enqueue_style() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'customCSS', get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/filename.css' ); 
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themename_enqueue_style' );
```

`get_template_directory_uri()` prints the **template directory** link.

**Example:**
www.example.com/wp-content/themes/themename